# Spring JPA SQLException: Implicit conversion from datatype INTO to CHAR

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting an implicit conversion error when doing my JOINS between ClientAccount and ProductDescription through Spring JPA. I am not sure where the conversion is happening. I am using Sybase.

Error:

```
Hibernate: select productdes0_.ProductID as ProductID1_2_0_, productdes0_.LanguageID as LanguageID3_2_0_, productdes0_.CountryID as CountryID2_2_0_, productdes0_.LengthID as LengthID4_2_0_, productdes0_.ProductID as ProductID1_2_1_, productdes0_.CountryID as CountryID2_2_1_, productdes0_.LanguageID as LanguageID3_2_1_, productdes0_.LengthID as LengthID4_2_1_, productdes0_.Description as Description5_2_1_ from ProductDescription productdes0_ where productdes0_.ProductID=? and productdes0_.LanguageID=? and productdes0_.CountryID=? and productdes0_.LengthID=?
18:23:28.005 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - could not extract ResultSet [n/a]
java.sql.SQLException: Implicit conversion from datatype 'INT' to 'CHAR' is not allowed.  Use the CONVERT function to run this query.

    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybConnection.getAllExceptions(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.handleSQLE(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.nextResult(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.queryLoop(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source) ~[jconn4-7.0.jar:?]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:70) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.getResultSet(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:434) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:186) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.initialize(AbstractLoadPlanBasedCollectionInitializer.java:88) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:688) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:75) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1991) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:570) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:252) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:566) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toArray(PersistentBag.java:283) [hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at com.bns.baas.deposit.account.account.query.DepositAccountService.getDepositAccountByKey(DepositAccountService.java:74) [main/:?]
    at com.bns.baas.deposit.account.account.query.DepositAccountService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$f2f69165.invoke(<generated>) [main/:?]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204) [spring-core-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96) [spring-tx-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) [spring-aop-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at com.bns.baas.deposit.account.account.query.DepositAccountService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$430deac8.getDepositAccountByKey(<generated>) [main/:?]
    at com.bns.baas.deposit.account.account.query.DepositAccountController.account(DepositAccountController.java:67) [main/:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[?:1.8.0_141]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:967) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:901) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846) [spring-webmvc-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55) [spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.trace.WebRequestTraceFilter.doFilterInternal(WebRequestTraceFilter.java:110) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.MetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(MetricsFilter.java:106) [spring-boot-actuator-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:478) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:80) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:799) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1455) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_141]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_141]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.15.jar:8.5.15]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_141]
```

ClientAccount.java

```
@Table(name="ClientAccount")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClientAccount {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientAccountKey key;

    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="LanguageID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="CountryID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="LengthID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private List<ProductDescription> productDescription;

}
```

ProductDescription.java

```
@Table(name="ProductDescription")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductDescription {
    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductDescriptionKey key;

    @Column(name = "Description", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="LanguageID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="CountryID", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name="LengthID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private ClientAccount clientAccount;
}
```

ProductDescriptionKey.java

```
@Setter
@Getter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Embeddable
public class ProductDescriptionKey implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ProductID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String ProductID;

    @Column(name = "LanguageID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String languageID;

    @Column(name = "CountryID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String countryID;

    @Column(name = "LengthID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String lengthID;
}
```

[ProductDescription SQL Table Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTgMD.jpg)

[ProductDescription SQL Table primary key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nQWad.jpg)

Can anyone help determine where I might be wrong?

Comment: Where are your primary Keys defined? As far as I know, you need to define at least one in JPA

Comment: I added snapshot of the primary key in the original post.

Comment: Why are your using `insertable = false, updatable = false` everywhere? please add a full stack of the exception? secondly, one of side the relationship `ProductDescription` <--> `ClientAccount` should own the association, I suggest to you to use @OneToMany with `mappedby` (no need for @JoinColumn on both side), you can write  `@OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="clientAccount")`

Comment: @O.Badr I just added the entire entire exception stack.

Comment: It looks like Hibernate tries to link `@JoinColumns` of `ProductDescription.clientAccount` with `ClientAccount.key`, and I guess that `key` contains an `int` field.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Type of productId from String to Integer or Long in your Productdescriptionkey class, as this represents your Primary Key.

Comment: I just tried and it gave me same error. I added the stack trace in the original post. Is there a way to add convert to attributes in ProductDescriptionKey?

Answer (score 0):

I can't get much information from the exception, but I will try to correct some mapping issue which it may cause the exception

**First**: ClientAccount.java should be (as you use bidirectional association):

```
@Table(name="ClientAccount")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ClientAccount {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ClientAccountKey key;

    @OneToMany (fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "clientAccount")
    private List<ProductDescription> productDescription;    
}
```

ProductDescriptionKey.java

```
Table(name="ProductDescription")
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class ProductDescription {

    @EmbeddedId
    private ProductDescriptionKey key;

    @Column(name = "Description", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private String description;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name="ClientAccountKeyField1_Fk_ColumnName", referencedColumnName = "ClientAccountKeyField1_Pk_ColumnName"),
        @JoinColumn(name="ClientAccountKeyField2_Fk_ColumnName", referencedColumnName = "ClientAccountKeyField2_Pk_ColumnName"),
//... other @JoinColumn
    })
    private ClientAccount clientAccount;
}
```

As you notice, in [@JoinColumn](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) you should use `ClientAccountKey` fields and not `ProductDescriptionKey` as these column will be created in `ProductDescription` to reference `ClientAccount` row.

...and, You should use [referencedColumnName](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#referencedColumnName()) when using [@JoinColumns](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumns.html), as stated in the documentation:

> When the JoinColumns annotation is used, both the name and the
>   referencedColumnName elements must be specified in each such
>   JoinColumn annotation

**Second**:
I don't think it's a good idea to use `insertable = false, updatable = false` in `ProductDescriptionKey` class, as you should have an ID to be persisted. But, if you want to have a read only entity use [@Immutabl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/Immutable.html) instead.

Hope it solves the issue!